# Should [morning-hacks] be a tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Apart from losing the -hacks suffix, is this tag useful? If we allow it, does it allow for other temporal tags like [night](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/night), [evening](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evening), etc?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### No.

What value does it add? Can someone be an more experienced with lifehacks dealing with the morning than they are with other lifehacks?

Comment: Frankly, [home] should suffice.